# Using filter for int's inside tuples

Tags: haskell

```
type MakeUp = (String, String, Int)

stuff :: [MakeUp]
stuff =[("eye liner","MAC",250),("foundation","YSL",800),("toner","GIVENCHY",700),("lip gloss","BENEFIT",900),("bronzer","BENEFIT",500)]

listAllSold :: String -> [MakeUp] -> [MakeUp] 
listAllSold nameOfBrand stuff = [] 

mostSold :: [MakeUp] -> [MakeUp]
mostSold stuff = []
```

`listAllSold "BENEFIT" stuff` should give:

```
[("lip gloss","BENEFIT",900),("bronzer","BENEFIT",500)]
```

and `mostSold stuff` should give:

```
("lip gloss","BENEFIT",900)
```

as it has the most sold.

How should I go about coding these functions? Using filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using tuples

The first function can be written using `filter`:

```
listAllSold :: String -> [MakeUp] -> [MakeUp] 
listAllSold nameOfBrand = filter (\(_, n, _) -> n == nameOfBrand)
```

The second using `maximumBy`:

```
mostSold :: [MakeUp] -> MakeUp
mostSold = maximumBy (\(_, _, a) (_, _, b) -> compare a b)
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf69d645482fea36)

*Note: `maximumBy` is imported by `Data.List`*.

### Using a data type

You should probably consider to use a data type instead of a tuple:

```
data MakeUp
    = MakeUp
        { a :: String
        , b :: String
        , c :: Int }
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Then you can define `listAllSold` as:

```
listAllSold :: String -> [MakeUp] -> [MakeUp] 
listAllSold nameOfBrand = filter ((== nameOfBrand) . b)
```

and `mostSold` as:

```
mostSold :: [MakeUp] -> MakeUp
mostSold = maximumBy (compare `on` c)
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12c77a60dfdd39dc)

*Note: `maximumBy` is imported by `Data.List`*.
*Note: `on` is imported by `Data.Function`*.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint, write accessor functions for your tuple type:

```
makeupCategory :: MakeUp -> String
makeupCategory (category, company, sold) = category

makeupCompany :: MakeUp -> String
makeupCompany (category, company, sold) = company

makeupAmountSold :: MakeUp -> Int
makeupAmountSold (category, company, sold) = sold
```

These are very simple functions, but now you can use them elsewhere.  Now look at the type of `filter`:

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

We want to pass it a list of `MakeUp`s, so we can say that `a ~ MakeUp`:

```
filter :: (MakeUp -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

Now you can write a function

```
isProductOf :: String -> MakeUp -> Bool
isProductOf brand makeup = ???
```

And use it with `filter`.